# Extract macros from locked workbook

Tags: excel, vba, locked

I've accidentally and unintentionally put a password on a workbook which I can therefore no longer open. I have the previous version unlocked, however the latest version has updated macros. Is there any way to extract the macros from the protected workbook without knowing the password?

Comment: Saving a workbook with a password does not prevent opening the workbook. You need to enter the password, then you can open the workbook. If it were simple to extract content from a password-protected workbook, what would be the point of using a password in the first place??!!  Also, if I had a dollar for every question where people claim that they have forgotten the password, I'd be rich. On a forum like this, how would one know if somebody wants to access stuff they shouldn't or if they have genuinely forgotten a password to content they own?

Comment: Confused by your comment "saving a workbook with a password does not prevent opening the workbook". Is that now that point of a password?

Comment: I'm just trying to save re-do ALL of Friday's work if possible.

Comment: Your question reads as if the act of putting a password on a workbook means that you cannot open it ("which I can therefore no longer open"). But a workbook protected with a password CAN be opened. You just have to supply the password. The reason you cannot open it is not that it's password protected. I have many workbooks that are password protected and I can open them all. The reason you can't open it is that you have not supplied the correct password.

Comment: Make a copy of your book, rename the extension from "*.xlsm" to "*.zip", then if you unzip the zip file and you will find a /xl/vbaProject.bin within the ZIP archive. This is the binary file which contains the macros

Answer (score 1):

There is a minimum number of characters for an answer, but the short version is:

No.